# How to perform this operation in Mathematica?

Tags: simulation

Let S be a vector of 1000 Elements (nonzero elements: output of some calculations).

Let T be a vector of 10 elements (nonzero elements: output of some calculations).

Let C be a vector of 10 elements (same size of T). All the elements are initialised with 0.

I need to perform this:

for s=1:length(S)

for t=1:length(T)

if S(s)>T(t)

C(t)=C(t)+1

end

end

How can I perform this?

Comment: @kuba, Right you are..

Answer (score 2):

If I understand this is a verbatim translation of your pseudocode.

```
sS = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 1000];
tT = RandomInteger[{1, 9}, 10];
cC = ConstantArray[0, 10];
Do[If[sS[[s]] > tT[[t]], cC[[t]]++], {s, Length@sS}, {t, Length@tT}];

cC
```

> ```
> {107, 547, 0, 456, 0, 685, 0, 795, 456, 685}
> ```

Note that I use `sS`, etc. because Symbols starting with capital letters may be reserved, as indeed [`C`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/C.html) is.

Is this what you want?  If so the *Mathematica* way would be something like this:

```
Tr @ UnitStep[sS - # - 1] & /@ tT
```

> ```
> {107, 547, 0, 456, 0, 685, 0, 795, 456, 685}
> ```